# Mongodb Doesn't start from Service

Tags: mongodb, service, ubuntu-16.04

It might look like a `Duplicate Question` to you but it is not. I have a mongo setup, previously it was running locally. It worked fine. The moment I decided to make use of it from `external IP`, I was unable to start it from service. Also, I have a service configuration like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
After=network.target
Documentation=https://docs.mongodb.org/manual

[Service]
User=mongodb
Group=mongodb
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongod.conf
# file size
LimitFSIZE=infinity
# cpu time
LimitCPU=infinity
# virtual memory size
LimitAS=infinity
# open files
LimitNOFILE=64000
# processes/threads
LimitNPROC=64000
# total threads (user+kernel)
TasksMax=infinity
TasksAccounting=false

# Recommended limits for for mongod as specified in
# http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/ulimit/#recommended- 
settings

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and mongo.conf like this:

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
journal:
  enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0


#processManagement:

security:
  authorization:'enabled'

#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

Before changing following line to: `bindIp: 0.0.0.0`  from `bindIp: 127.0.0.1`. And added following line: 
`security:
  authorization:'enabled'`

Also logs of service are: `Oct 11 13:42:27 bingagepos-sandbox systemd[1]: Started High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database.
Oct 11 13:42:27 bingagepos-sandbox systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
Oct 11 13:42:27 bingagepos-sandbox systemd[1]: mongod.service: Unit entered failed state.
Oct 11 13:42:27 bingagepos-sandbox systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'`

If I run following command it works fine:

```
mongod --dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb
```

It stopped working. Now if I start it from service it doesn't start.
Can anyone tell what could be done? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling a lot I got the following solution:

First of all I changed following line in serve file:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf --quiet
```

after that, I made the following changes in the conf file.

```
authorization:[spaceadded]'enabled'
```

After that I ran following command to change permissions of data dir:

```
cd /path/to/data
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb *
```

Regards